# How to show EXT js Grid with .log data file?

Tags: javascript, gridview, extjs

I have a .log file. I have created one grid example in EXT JS to show log data from json file(mock data). Now i want to show the grid data from the .log file. What will be the best way to do it? Can convert .log file to .json file (by parsing or say somw how) or is there any better/sensible way to do the same?

Comment: How does the log file look like?

Comment: standard log4j log file....tab based..
say,
aa bb cc dd ee ff gg
bb kk bb vv xx ii aa
.
.
.
.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get your data differently via Ajax request.

```
// Should work also in newer ExtJS versions
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
  width: 640,
  height: 480,
  store: new Ext.data.ArrayStore({
    fields: ['id', 'val1', 'val2'],
    data: []
  }),
  columns: [{
    dataIndex: 'id',
    text: 'Id'
  }, {
    dataIndex: 'val1',
    text: 'Value #1'
  }, {
    dataIndex: 'val2',
    text: 'Value #2'
  }],
  listeners: {
    afterrender: function(grid) {
      // Do an Ajax request
      Ext.Ajax.request({
        url: 'data1.log',
        // Will go here, because there is no such file...
        // When you provide a file it will be success and you can handle failure differently
        failure: function(response) {
          // responseText will be response.responseText on success
          // this here is only a mock
          var responseText =    "id1\tval1a\tval1b\nid2\tval2a\tval2b\nid3\tval3a\tval3b",
            data = [];

          // Split your data on new lines and iterate
          Ext.each(responseText.split('\n'), function (record) {
            // Create an empty array
            var item = [];
            // Split your new line-split on tab and iterate
            Ext.each(record.split('\t'), function (recordItem) {
                // push to your new data item
                item.push(recordItem);
            });
            // push to your data
            data.push(item);
          });
          // load the store
          grid.store.loadRawData(data);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

I provided an example on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4Lx818ua/

Good luck.